# SwiftUI ForEach force UI update when updating the contents of a core data relationship

Tags: core-data, swiftui

My app is meant to have a bunch of workouts in core data, each with a relationship to many exercises.  A view should display the data in each workout (name, description etc.) and then iterate and display each exercise belonging to that workout.

Adding exercises and displaying them works fine.  If an exercise is deleted, however it:

- deletes from coredata no worries
- the information seems to delete from iterableExercises
- however, the Text line does not disappear.  it goes from, for example "Squat, Description" to simply " , "
- If I close the app entirely and reopen, then the " , " lines do completely disappear.

The problem code:

```
if let iterableExercises = workout.exercises?.array as? [ExerciseEntity] {
    ForEach(iterableExercises) {exercise in
        Text("\(exercise.name ?? ""), \(exercise.desc ?? "")")
    }
}
```

I've got the entity relationship set as ordered, but I've also tried unordered with .allObjects instead of .array.  This clearly isn't the problem as it's the array iterableExercises that's not correctly being reset?

EDIT: to reproduce, here's all the code you need and some screenshots of the CoreData model.

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    let container: NSPersistentCloudKitContainer
    @Published var savedWorkouts: [WorkoutEntity] = []
    @Published var savedExercises: [ExerciseEntity] = []


    // MARK: INIT
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentCloudKitContainer(name: "mre")
        container.loadPersistentStores { description, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error loading CoreData: \(error)")
            }
        }
        fetchWorkoutEntities()
        fetchExerciseEntities()
    }

    // MARK: FETCHERS
    func fetchWorkoutEntities() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<WorkoutEntity>(entityName: "WorkoutEntity")
        do {
            savedWorkouts = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching WorkoutEntity: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    func fetchExerciseEntities() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<ExerciseEntity>(entityName: "ExerciseEntity")
        do {
            savedExercises = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching ExerciseEntity: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: SAVE
    func saveData() {
        do {
            try container.viewContext.save()
            fetchWorkoutEntities()
            fetchExerciseEntities()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error saving: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    // MARK: ADDERS
    func addWorkout(name: String) {
        let _ = WorkoutEntity(context: container.viewContext)
        saveData()
    }
    
    func addExerciseToWorkout(workout: WorkoutEntity, name: String) {
        let newExercise = ExerciseEntity(context: container.viewContext)
        newExercise.name = name
        workout.addToExercises(newExercise)
        saveData()
    }
    
    // MARK: DELETERS
    func deleteWorkout(workout: WorkoutEntity) {
        container.viewContext.delete(workout)
        saveData()
    }
    
    func deleteExercise(exercise: ExerciseEntity) {
        container.viewContext.delete(exercise)
        saveData()
    }
    // MARK: TODO: UPDATERS
}


struct ContentView: View {
    
    @StateObject var data = ViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button {
                data.addWorkout(name: "workout")
                data.addExerciseToWorkout(workout: data.savedWorkouts[0], name: "[exercisename]")
            } label: {
                Text("Click ONCE to add workout to work with")
            }
            Spacer()
            if let iterableExercises = data.savedWorkouts[0].exercises?.array as? [ExerciseEntity] {
                ForEach(iterableExercises) { exercise in
                    Button {
                        data.deleteExercise(exercise: exercise)
                    } label: {
                        Text("Click to delete \(exercise.name ?? "") AFTER DELETING IF THIS STILL SHOWS BUT DOESN'T SHOW THE EXERCISE NAME THEN IT'S BROKEN")
                    }
                }
            }
            Spacer()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

[screenshots of model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TkRfT.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (MRE)](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Also, Core Data can be a struggle to make an MRE simply because of the model. You can screenshot your model to post the MRE. Also, please make it minimal.

Comment: All CoreData objects should be wrapped in an @ObservedObject

Comment: Updating the post with an MRE (as minimal as possible which isn't very minimal, but if you copy paste it all into a content view and make a simple relationship as screenshotted, it should demonstrate the issue).

I have my class as ViewModel: ObservableObject and wrapped in \@StateObject.  I tried \@ObservedObject instead, same issue, no difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I’m not sure if this is the ONLY solution as @malhal gave quite an extensive and seemingly useful response.

But I came across a much easier and immediate fix, within my original solution. The inverse relationships must be specified. Doing this resolved all issues.

Answer (score -1):

We don't use view model objects in SwiftUI. You need to learn the View struct and property wrappers which gives the consistency and efficiency of value types with the benefits of reference types. The property wrapper for core data is `@FetchRequest` which invalidates the View when the results change. It's also a `DynamicProperty` (which is how it gets the context from the environment) that you can use it directly without the property wrapper syntax which allows you to use a param in a predicate, in your case to do fetch the one-to-many relation, e.g.

```
struct WorkoutView: View {

    private var fetchRequest: FetchRequest<Exercise>
    private var exercices: FetchedResults<Exercise> {
        fetchRequest.wrappedValue
    }

    init(workout: Workout) {
        let sortAscending = true
        let sortDescriptors = [SortDescriptor(\Exercise.timestamp, order: sortAscending ? .forward : .reverse)]
        fetchRequest = FetchRequest(sortDescriptors: sortDescriptors, predicate: NSPredicate(format: "workout = %@", workout), animation: .default)
    }

    var body: some View {
        List(exercises) { exercise in
            ExerciseView(exercise: exercise)
        }
    }
}
```

For creating the `NSPersistentContainer` check out the Xcode App template with Core Data checked. Looks like this:

```
@main
struct TestApp: App {
    let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(\.managedObjectContext, persistenceController.container.viewContext)
            
        }
    }
```

The reason it is not an `@StateObject` is we don't want to invalidate this body when it changes and we need it to be init for previewing which is a different singleton.

```
struct PersistenceController {
    static let shared = PersistenceController()

    static var preview: PersistenceController = {
        let result = PersistenceController(inMemory: true)
... see template
```

That other code in your view model class can be moved to `NSManagedObject` and `NSManagedObjectContext` extensions. Use the Editor menu to generate the `NSManagedObject` extension for the model, the files need tidying up though and make sure use extension is selected for the entity.